# How to Sniff Symbian OS Nokia Phone Network Connections?

Tags: symbian, nokia, s60

How to Sniff Symbian OS(S60 platform) Nokia Phone Network Connections? I need to see the network traffic of my Nokia Phone...

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to sniff IP traffic, there is an API to do that - IPHook. However, its not simple, poorly documented and requires capabilities which may require the blessing of a handset manufacturer (since its an obvious security hole!).

See [discussion on deploying IPHook](http://developer.symbian.com/forum/message.jspa?messageID=80282)

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, I do not want to do some coding. I just need an application like Ethereal or Microsoft Network Monitor to sniff (Nokia N80 with Symbian S60 OS)a phone network traffic(GPRS data flow, 3G data flow, WAP data flow).

Comment: There isn't one freely available that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure if it is possible, but, maybe you can connect your handset through wifi and sniff its traffic on PC (only if this device has wifi).